# Salesforce Questions Preparing for Exam

Tags: certification

I am preparing for exam in the meanwhile i got some questions,answers to these questions are doubtful to me.Please guide me with correct answers for the following questions.

```
Q.1 Of the following, what are the things not possible to include in the user page
layout (Choose two)
a. Tagging
b. Custom links
c. Inline Visualforce page
d. Custom buttons
e. Custom fields

Q.2 A manager wants to share specific fields of data with his subordinates that
only he has access to. What is the best way to share specific fields of data?
Please select two choices.
a. Select the view dashboard as with his own name
b. Folder permission on a report
c. Run report as scheduled reports and e-mail distribution
d. Folder permission on a dashboard


Q.3)What will cause the analytic snapshots run to fail?
Please select three (3) choices.
a. The source report has been deleted
b. The target object has a trigger on it
c. The running user has been inactivated
d. The target object is a custom object
e. The source report is saved as matrix report

Q.4)In Master-Detail relationship scenario the fields of the parent object need to
be displayed in the related list. How will a developer design this?
a. Cross-object formula field
b. Workflow rule
c. Validation rule
d. Assignment rule

Q.5)In a recruiting application a position that is of type critical should not be kept
open for more than 14 days. How will you develop the business logic to cater
to this?
a. Time-dependant workflow action to send an e-mail to the owner after
14 days
b. Time-dependant workflow action to send the record for review to
owner after 14 days
c. Time-dependant workflow action to send an e-mail to the owner
before 14 days
d. Time-dependant workflow action to close the position after 14 days

Q.6)An organization wants to leverage a custom objects to track bugs.the organization wants the ability to related bugs to parent bugs in a parent-child relationship.What type of relationship should be used?
a)Master Detail
b)Self
c)Hierarchical
d)Many to Many

Q.7)A business requirement can be met by using a either a formula field or an apex trigger why should a developer use a formula field instead of an apex trigger.
choose two answers
a)formula fields do not require test methods to deploy.
b)formula fields allow a greater control and flexibility
c)formula fields can be created and display only in web browser
d)formula fields can aggregate data from child records. 

Q.8)Which standard profile has the "view encrypted data" permission by default?
a)solution manager
b)Standard user
c)system administrator
d)No profile has this permission by default.
```

Comment: This question isn't constructive and doesn't fit well with the site, and the questions posed in the list aren't accurate either. There are some good blog posts and other sources around to help prepare for the 401 exam. Doing a search on www.findsf.info will get you off to a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Q.8)Which standard profile has the "view encrypted data" permission by default?

A) d) No profile has this permission by default.